# ¿Cómo cambiar el estilo de los submenús en ASP.NET?

Tags: css, asp.net

Estoy creando menú desplegable en ASP.NET, pero cuando trato de cambiarle el estilo con `LevelSubMenuStyles` no hace los cambios, se quedan igual los items.

Este es mi código:

```
<asp:Menu ID="viewsMenu" BackColor="#008a5f" runat="server" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100%" Height="25px">
    <StaticHoverStyle ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="White" Font-Bold="true"/>
    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="4px" ForeColor="White" />
    <StaticSelectedStyle ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="White" Font-Bold="true" />
    <LevelSubMenuStyles>
        <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="MenuItems" />
    </LevelSubMenuStyles>
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Vistas" Value="'Vistas" NavigateUrl="#">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Tabla" Value="Tabla" NavigateUrl="~/TableView.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Gráficas" Value="Gráficas"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Layout" Value="Layout" NavigateUrl="~/LayoutView.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Esta es mi clase de estilos:

```
.MenuItems
{
    background-color:rgb(0, 138, 95);
    color:white;
    border:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:white;
}
```

Pero cuando despliega los items del menú Vistas muestra sólo las letras y no muestra ni fondo ni borde.

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo no funciona por que nunca le agregas la clase a los items solo al fragmento de codigo LevelSubMenuStyles, que por lo que veo es un separador del menu y los items por eso es que se muestra mas larga la opcion vistas.

Lo que te propongo es que ubiques alguna de las clases que tienen los item y a esa le agregues el estilo en este caso veo 2 alternativas que pueden ayudarte,
poner los estilos en la clase dinamic o level2, al ponerlo en alguna de las 2 los items toman los estilos que requieres.

te dejo el codigo a continuacion

```
.dynamic {
        background-color: rgb(0, 138, 95);
        color: white;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: white;
    }

.level2{
        background-color: rgb(0, 138, 95);
        color: white;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: white;
    }
```